# Unable to post file content on guzzle multiform request

Tags: php, guzzle6

I am trying to post image content as a parameter of the multiform request. The following code works.

```
$read_image = base64_encode(file_get_contents('Large.jpg'));
$client = new Client(['debug' => true ,'handler' => $stack,]);
  $request = $client->Request(
    'POST',
    'https://mylandoapp.lndo.site/testdrive/post',
    [ 
      'multipart' => 
      [
        [
          'name'     => 'image',
          'contents' =>   $read_image,
        ],
      ],
    ]
  );
```

I am able to get the value using following code.

```
$data =$request->request->all();
$my_image = $data[$image];
```

When I try to add the file name, the image content is an empty array.

```
$request = $client->Request(
    'POST',
    'https://mylandoapp.lndo.site/testdrive/post',
    [ 
      'multipart' => 
      [
        [
          'name'     => 'image',
          'contents' =>  $read_image,
          'filename' => 'custom_filename.txt',
        ],
      ],
    ]);
```

How can I pass file name a well as file content using multiform post request?

Comment: @revo  if you know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

Could be trivial, but first check that is actually a Guzzle issue and not a php memory limit issue. Base64 encoding a "Large.jpg" will triple the string length of $read_image. Check the php error log to see if your not running out of buffer length. I would try with a smaller JPEG first.